# Bootstrap Vue + Nuxt JS modal problem inside v-for

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm building a "Trello" like application whereby I have boards, lists and cards and data is saved to a real time database in Firebase for testing.

I'm using Bootstrap Vue's [modals](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal#toggle-modal-visibility) to toggle the visibility. However, I'm getting a problem...

To start, I have my `<b-modal>` within a Bootstrap card which has a `v-for` which fetches a list of cards from a list of lists which are in boards. And i want to show the card's data once clicked within the modal, and if I click another card then it will use the same `<b-modal>` element but display different data.

With my implementation, I appear to be causing a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` and literally it errors 5,000 + times crashing the browser, it's not looking good :D

I've done some debugging, and have tried using methods with a `return false;` to find out what's actually happening, and the modal shows, but when dismissing the modal the modal pops straight up again, thus causing the error.

Below, I attach the relevant code and JS:

**HTML Markup**

```
<b-col md="4" v-for="(list, index) in board.lists" :key="list.id">
              <b-card bg-variant="light" header-tag="header" footer-tag="footer">
                <div slot="header" class="mb-0">
                  <b-row>
                    <b-col md="8">
                      <h4 class="mb-0"><b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2 input-is-editable" type="text" placeholder="Enter list name..." v-model="list.name" /></h4>
                    </b-col>
                  </b-row>
                </div>
                <b-card class="mb-3" v-for="(card, index) in list.cards" :key="card.id" v-b-modal.prevent="modalId(index)">{{ card.name }}
                  <b-modal :id="'modal' + index" hide-footer title="Using Component Methods">
                    <div class="d-block text-center">
                      <h3>{{ card.name }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <b-button class="mt-3" variant="outline-danger" block>Close Me</b-button>
                  </b-modal>
                </b-card>
                <div slot="footer" class="mb-0">
                  <b-row>
                    <b-col>
                      <b-nav-form>
                        <b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Enter card name..." v-model="cardname" />
                        <b-button size="sm" variant="success" class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" @click="addCard(index)" :disabled="!cardname">Add card</b-button>
                      </b-nav-form>
                    </b-col>
                  </b-row>
                </div>
              </b-card>
            </b-col>
```

**JS**

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      board: [],
      cards: [],
      lists: [],
      listname: '',
      cardname: '',
      editedFields: {}
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get('myfirebaseurl/boards/' + this.id + '.json').then(response => {
      this.board = response.body
    }, response => {
      // handle error for fetching property data.
    });
  },
  methods: {
    modalId(index) {
      return 'modal' + index;
    }
  }
}
```

There is more to the JS, however I'm only attaching what's relevant to the markup above.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix?

[image]

many thanks!

Comment: You probably shouldn't have the modal in a v-for. If you put it at the top of your html you can have an @click event inside a v-for that passes the required data to the modal and opens it.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather agree with @Andrew1325 who pointed out that creating a single instance of modal dialog and passing the selected data might be a better option, for example

```
 <div>
    <div v-for="(item) in items" :key="item.id">
      <b-card
        :title="item.title"
        :img-src="item.imageUrl"
        img-alt="Image"
        img-top
        tag="article"
        style="max-width: 20rem;"
        class="mb-2"
      >
        <b-card-text>{{item.text}}</b-card-text>

        <b-button variant="primary" @click="showModal(item)">Show details</b-button>
      </b-card>
    </div>
    <b-modal id="modal1" :title="selectedItem.title">
      <img style="max-width: 20rem;" :src="selectedItem.imageUrl"/>
      <p class="my-4">{{selectedItem.text}}</p>
    </b-modal>
</div>



export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItem: {},
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "First",
          imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/600/300/?image=23",
          text: "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/600/300/?image=24",
          title: "Second",
          text: "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          imageUrl : "https://picsum.photos/600/300/?image=25",
          title: "Third",
          text: "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showModal(item){
      this.selectedItem = item;
      this.$root.$emit("bv::show::modal", "modal1");
    }
  }
};
```

**[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/733xo5v390)**